# Create trigger to automatically insert row in other table first

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

there are two tables in my SQL 2012 DB. Tables: Voyages and Countries.

The table Voyages contains the information "destinationID" (which represents the according countryID). The data for Voyages is being imported from a text file that contains the country's names. 
What I wanted achieve is the following:

1. When a new row is added to the Voyages table, a new row will be added to the Countries table first (generating a new countryID and inserting the country's name).
2. When the new Country row is added, the generated countryID will then be used to insert a new Voyages row (setting the countryID as destinationID).

I know I could do this in my application by parsing the text file, extracting the country name, and adding it to the DB in order to get the new countryID. Then I could add a new Voyages row using the new ID. But could I also do the whole Job in the DB? I thought about using a Trigger.

But then I would have the problem that I initially would have to insert a country name string to the Voyages table, while in the end I want to insert a countryID (int) instead.

This would be some sort of Workaround which I really don't like:

```
INSERT INTO voyages (voyageID, destinationID, destinationString) VALUES (1, 0, "BRAZIL");
```

Like this, I could create a Trigger (INSTEAD OF INSERT) that extracts destinationString in order to insert a new country row:

```
INSERT INTO countries (countryName) VALUES ("BRAZIL");
```

The resulting countryID (e.g. 27) could then be used inside my trigger to finally insert the new row to voyages:

```
INSERT INTO voyages (voyageID, destinationID, destinationString) VALUES (1, 27, NULL);
```

Is there any more elegant way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could import the data into an intermediate table "VoyageImport". A trigger on this table could update the two other tables. The VoyageImport table could then be cleared regularly. Not very elegant I know, but it is one method.

Comment: You should use stored procedure to do this.

Comment: allow me to discourage using any kind trigger in this case? what would happen if you have more than one new country generated? how do you expect get the different IDs?

Comment: @Nenad: Didn't think about it. I'll give it a try! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mentioned stored procedure in the comment as best solution for this kind of problem. Here is a sample how it could look:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspInsertVoyage
(
    @voyageID INT, 
    @destinationString NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @destinationID INT;

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Countries WHERE countryName = @destinationString)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO countries (countryName) VALUES (@destinationString)
    END;

    SELECT @destinationID = countryID FROM Countries WHERE countryName = @destinationString;

    INSERT INTO voyages (voyageID, destinationID, destinationString) VALUES (@voyageID, @destinationID, NULL);

END
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much! 
Just what I needed!!

Thanks again.